# StackExchange Redis Subscribe usage

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

Reading on the basic usage of [Pub/Sub](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Basics.html#using-redis-pubsub) for stack exchange redis, it says the `ISubscriber` object "is a cheap pass-thru object that does not need to be stored."
That makes me wonder: it's the subscription callback kept after the `ISubscriber` object is disposed?
Can I get another `ISubscriber` later to unsubscribe the callback I registered earlier?

Just wondering if this is the proper usage:

```cs
// .. method 1
ISubscriber sub = redis.GetSubscriber();
sub.Subscribe("messages", (channel, message) => {
    Console.WriteLine((string)message);
});
// ... sub it's discarded.

// method 2
ISubscriber sub2 = redis.GetSubscriber();
sub2.Unsubscribe("messages"); // removes the call back set in method 1?
```